# Control Neopixel with SPI on an ATmega32U4

Tags: spi, atmega32u4

I want to control one Neopixel using an ATmega32U4 (only one, so there is no problem with chain timing propagation). With the bit-banging library it does work great, but I want to use the SPI to free up the processor a bit.

The problem I see is that when a byte has been transmitted, the MOSI line seems to be set to HIGH, when I need it to be LOW. This is a problem because it makes the Neopixel believe that there is a new bit coming.

Is there a way of ensuring that the MOSI line is set to LOW, or, at least, to the last sent bit value?

If there is no way of doing that with SPI, can it be done with the UART in SPI mode?

P.D.: Of course, I know that I can build an inverter with a transistor and a resistor to fix that externally, but if there is a pure "software" solution, I would prefer it.

Comment: Are you talking about WS2812 LEDs?

Comment: Please describe how your pulses are mapped into your SPI data bits. It may vary based on the MCU, but the last bit transmitted normally just stays on the bus.

Comment: @SadatRafi Yes, WS2812B (800Kbps)

Comment: @Mattman944 I set the SPI clock to 4MHz (fc/4) and send 0x80 for a "zero" and a 0xE0 for a "one". When I use SPI_MODE0 or SPI_MODE2, the B2 pin remains high when the transmission ended, but if I use SPI_MODE1 it remains low and it *seems* to work, although sometimes (it happened twice) there seems to be a transmission error.

Comment: One bit high is 250 nS, right at the edge of the requirement (400 nS +/- 150). You haven't allowed for any deviation in the signal propagation. If you can set your SPI clock to 2.666 MHz (16/6), and use 3 SPI bit periods per WS2812 bit (2 WS2812 bits per SPI byte), then you will have some margin.

Comment: @Mattman944 But the documentation I have says the requirement for zero is 350 +/- 150...

Comment: @Mattman944 Ok, my fault: it is an SK6812. The timings are 300 +/- 150 for a zero, and 600 +/- 150 for a one.